# How to search two paths but get the results in order using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to search for elements with prefix `w` and also `t` or `br` using Nokogiri.

For example if this is the core of the `doc` returned from parsing:

```
<w:t></w:t><w:br></w:br><w:t></w:t>
```

This search

```
doc.search('.//w:t','.//w:br')
```

Results in:

```
['<w:t></w:t>','<w:t></w:t>','<w:br></w:br>']
```

Instead I want (the elements are in the order of the original doc):

```
['<w:t></w:t>','<w:br></w:br>','<w:t></w:t>']
```

Comment: When asking, we need to see the absolute minimal code and input data (HTML or XML), along with your required output. Without that you're asking us to imagine the code, the document or the output, which results in wildly divergent answers and don't help you or anyone after you wanting a solution to the same problem. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. As a hint though, `,` in your selector is the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan no problem, I updated my post accordingly

Comment: "`w:`" isn't a "prefix", it's a namespace, and is a significant part of the structure of the XML. _Sometimes_ you can dispense with it, other times you have to honor it. The Nokogiri docs cover this.

Comment: Show us the tag with the namespace declaration, along with one or two lines you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man)'s response, the answer I was looking for is this

```
doc.search('.//w:t | .//w:br')
```

Comment: You probably don't want `.//`. `//` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS selectors you can do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
  <t></t><br></br><t></t>
</xml>
EOT

doc.search('t, br')
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c name="t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x50 name="br">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x64 name="t">]

doc.search('t, br').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<t></t>", "<br>", "<t></t>"]
```

CSS selectors are recommended by Nokogiri's authors because they're generally easier and less noisy.

Using XPath, this'd work:

```
doc.search('//t | //br')
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c name="t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x50 name="br">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x64 name="t">]

doc.search('//t | //br').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<t></t>", "<br>", "<t></t>"]
```

However, your XML has namespaces, and you didn't show us the appropriate namespace declaration so that's left for you to figure out.

See Nokogiri's [Namespaces](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces) documentation for more information.